# Laravel ApiException returning HTML response and not JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to figure out why my ApiException is still returning a text/html response instead of a json response as denoted in ApiException render method. It is giving me the correct error message however its not rendering it as json.

```
/**
 * Get the checklist (depending on type - send from Vue model)
 */
public function fetchChecklist(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->input('projectId');
    $type = $request->input('type');

    if (empty($id)) {
        throw new ApiException('Project was not provided.');
    }

    if (! $project = RoofingProject::find($id)) {
        throw new ApiException('Project not found.');
    }

    if (empty($type)) {
        throw new ApiException('No checklist type was provided.');
    }

    switch ($request->input('type')) {
        case 'permitting':
            $items = $project->permittingChecklist;
            break;

        case 'permit':
            $items = $project->permitReqChecklist;
            break;

        default:
            throw new ApiException('Checklist not found.');
            break;
    }

    return [
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => '',
        'items' => $items
    ];
}
```

App\Exceptions\ApiException.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

class ApiException extends \Exception
{
    public function render($request)
    {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'error' => $this->message]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like there should be a `catch(ApiException $ex){ ... }` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Well it's not even hitting the render method at all because if I do a dd() in the render method it doesn't dump whatever I add.

Comment: Does `throw new ApiException('Project not found.');` call the `render` method without a `catch`? Would you need to call `catch(ApiException $ex){ return $ex->render(); }`?

Comment: In the Handler class I do have this. `if (method_exists('render', $exception)) {
            return $exception->report();
        }`

Comment: Ok... I don't understand this implementation, all I can see right now is that you're throwing an uncaught exception in your code, but I'm not going to comment with the same thing for a third time. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

In your request to the API you can try to add the following to your head/curl call to specify the datatype:

```
"Accept: application/json"
```

The laravel application is looking for if the requests expects json.

Comment: I looked inside of it and it currently does accept application/json but is not returning it.

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me with setting the following header as so

```
"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
```